# Duplicate entry exception

Tags: android, duplicates, dependencies

I am trying to execute Jacoco unit test and I get the below error

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':App:transformClassesWithJarMergingForTpsDebugAndroidTest'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/cyberneko/html/HTMLAugmentations.class

I tried to check in my dependencies, it never showed "org/cyberneko/html/HTMLAugmentations.class" in my dependencies.

I even tried the below configuration n never worked

```
 configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.cyberneko.html', module: 'org-cyberneko-html'
  }
```

Below are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {

  compile "com.comcast.cim:hypermedia-client:${hypermediaVersion}"
  compile ("com.comcast.xfinityhome:xhomeapi-client:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT") {
    exclude group: "commons-codec"

  }

  apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"

  compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:${aspectjVersion}"

  debugCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:${leakcanaryVersion}"
  releaseCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${leakcanaryVersion}"

  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
  compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
  compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
  compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0"
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${playServicesVersion}"

  // Needed for HelpShift
  compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
  compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"

  compile project(':svg-android')
  compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.0.4'
  compile(name:'video-player-module', ext:'aar')

  compile 'com.localytics.android:library:4.2+'
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${playServicesVersion}"
  compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:${jackson}"
  compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:${jackson}"
  compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jackson}"
  compile "oauth.signpost:signpost-core:${signpostVersion}"
  compile "oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:${signpostVersion}"
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'
  compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit1-okhttp3-client:1.0.2' // TODO remove once retrofit 2.0 is released
  compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${okhttpVersion}"
  compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.0.1"
  compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
  compile "io.reactivex:rxjava:${rxVersion}"
  compile "io.reactivex:rxandroid:${rxVersion}"
  compile "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0"
  compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
  compile "com.google.guava:guava:${guavaVersion}"
  compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.0.0'
  compile "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${timber}"
  compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${butterKnife}"
  apt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${butterKnife}"
  compile 'com.facebook.network.connectionclass:connectionclass:1.0.1'

  compile('net.openid:appauth:0.5.1'){
    transitive = false
  }
  compile "com.android.support:customtabs:${supportLibVersion}"

  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'

  compile ('com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1')
  compile ('com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar')

  compile 'com.helpshift:android-helpshift-en-aar:4.8.1' 

  testCompile "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"
  testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectricVersion}"
  testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:${powermockVersion}"
  testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:${powermockVersion}"
  testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:${powermockVersion}"
  testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:${powermockVersion}"

//  androidTestCompile "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"
  androidTestCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectricVersion}"
  androidTestCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:${powermockVersion}"
  //androidTestCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:${powermockVersion}"
  androidTestCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:${powermockVersion}"
  //androidTestCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:${powermockVersion}"

  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
  androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'design'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
  }

  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'
}
```

Comment: IMO from the description is unclear that problem really relates to JaCoCo. Also not sure that current description allows to reproduce problem - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve But here is wild guess: among your dependencies you have two different dependencies that provide the same class "org/cyberneko/html/HTMLAugmentations.class" and this causes exception ?

Comment: I don't know which class provides it. so I tried to exclude from couple of classes. doesn't seem to work, even it doesn show up in dependencies. not sure what to do. I edited my question